# Open port 22 to all instances within in my VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2

I need to have all eight instances in my VPC be able to communicate back and forth to each other on port 22(SSH).
I know how to set up the security groups for one instance to accept SSH traffic from another but I can not figure out how to set up the security groups to allow all the instances to talk to each other via SSH. There has to be an easy way. I tried putting all the instances in one security group and then assign that same security group to itself on port 22 but that did not work. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Were you using instance private IP address when testing ssh connectivity?

Comment: I was trying with private IP's. I do not want to use public.